# Parsing of XML with recursive hierarchy in Snowflake

Tags: xml, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to parse the below XML that has recursive hierarchal structure. I am able to loop through only once, the second survey data never gets populated. Also, I am getting NULL values in the columns

```
<DATA_EXPORT>
<SURVEYDATA>
    <SURVEY_ID>1</SURVEY_ID>
    <CLIENT_ID>ABC</CLIENT_ID>
    <COMMENTS>
      <RESPONSE>
        <QUESTION>Do you drink?</QUESTION>
        <ANSWER>Yes</ANSWER>
      </RESPONSE>
    </COMMENTS>
    <COMMENTS>
      <RESPONSE>
        <QUESTION>Do you Smoke?</QUESTION>
        <ANSWER>Yes</ANSWER>
      </RESPONSE>
    </COMMENTS>
</SURVEYDATA>
<SURVEYDATA>
    <SURVEY_ID>2</SURVEY_ID>
    <CLIENT_ID>DEF</CLIENT_ID>
    <COMMENTS>
      <RESPONSE>
        <QUESTION>Do you drink?</QUESTION>
        <ANSWER>No</ANSWER>
      </RESPONSE>
    </COMMENTS>
</SURVEYDATA>
</DATA_EXPORT>
```

Query used:

```
SELECT 
GET(XMLGET(XMLGET(TEST_XML_1, 'SURVEYDATA'),'SURVEY_ID'), '$') AS SURVEY_ID,
GET(XMLGET(D.VALUE, 'QUESTION'), '$') AS QUESTION,
GET(XMLGET(D.VALUE, 'ANSWER'), '$') AS ANSWER
FROM DATA,
LATERAL FLATTEN (GET(XMLGET(TEST_XML_1, 'SURVEYDATA', 0), '$'))D;
```

The output that I am getting is:

| SURVEY_ID | QUESTION | ANSWER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | NULL | NULL |

The output that I am expecting is:

| SURVEY_ID | QUESTION | ANSWER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Do you drink? | Yes |
| 1 | Do you smoke? | Yes |
| 2 | Do you drink? | No |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So seems you want to now loop across the object in `DATA_EXPORT` you need to get the object of that, which `GET(xml, '$')` will give you, thus the following will give you the two row of `SURVEYDATA`

```
SELECT q.*
FROM TEST_XML,
  LATERAL FLATTEN(GET(src_xml, '$')) q;
```

given you will want the survey_id and cleint_id lets pull those plus the nested comments out now, so we can see we are getting the data we want:

```
SELECT 
    get(XMLGET(q.value, 'SURVEY_ID'), '$') as survey_id
    ,get(XMLGET(q.value, 'CLIENT_ID'), '$') as client_id
    ,XMLGET(q.value, 'COMMENTS') as comments
FROM TEST_XML,
  LATERAL FLATTEN(GET(src_xml, '$')) q;
```

but we notice this only has one comment, so will need to loop not across the coments, but actually across the objects of SURVEYDATA but only keep the comments:

```
SELECT 
    get(XMLGET(q.value, 'SURVEY_ID'), '$') as survey_id
    ,get(XMLGET(q.value, 'CLIENT_ID'), '$') as client_id
    ,XMLGET(q.value, 'COMMENTS') as comments
    ,get(q.value, '$')
    ,c.*
FROM TEST_XML,
  LATERAL FLATTEN(GET(src_xml, '$')) q,
  LATERAL FLATTEN(get(q.value, '$')) c
WHERE get(c.value, '@')='COMMENTS'
```

now we can unpack the comments values we want:

```
SELECT 
    get(XMLGET(q.value, 'SURVEY_ID'), '$') as survey_id
    ,get(XMLGET(q.value, 'CLIENT_ID'), '$') as client_id
    ,c.value
    ,XMLGET(c.value, 'RESPONSE') as resp
    ,get(XMLGET(resp, 'QUESTION'), '$') as question
    ,get(XMLGET(resp, 'ANSWER'), '$' ) as answer
FROM TEST_XML,
  LATERAL FLATTEN(GET(src_xml, '$')) q,
  LATERAL FLATTEN(get(q.value, '$')) c
WHERE get(c.value, '@')='COMMENTS'
```

so now we can see we have all the values we want we can compress the SQL up a little so it doesn't have the intermediate values we used to help us work through the problem.

giving the final SQL, include data in a CTE to help test with:

```
with TEST_XML as (
  select parse_xml('<DATA_EXPORT>
  <SURVEYDATA>
    <SURVEY_ID>1</SURVEY_ID>
     <CLIENT_ID>ABC</CLIENT_ID>
     <COMMENTS>
       <RESPONSE>
         <QUESTION>Do you drink?</QUESTION>
         <ANSWER>Yes</ANSWER>
       </RESPONSE>
     </COMMENTS>
     <COMMENTS>
       <RESPONSE>
         <QUESTION>Do you Smoke?</QUESTION>
         <ANSWER>Yes</ANSWER>
       </RESPONSE>
     </COMMENTS>
   </SURVEYDATA>
   <SURVEYDATA>
     <SURVEY_ID>2</SURVEY_ID>
     <CLIENT_ID>DEF</CLIENT_ID>
     <COMMENTS>
       <RESPONSE>
         <QUESTION>Do you drink?</QUESTION>
         <ANSWER>No</ANSWER>
       </RESPONSE>
     </COMMENTS>
   </SURVEYDATA>
 </DATA_EXPORT>') as SRC_XML
  )
SELECT 
    get(XMLGET(q.value, 'SURVEY_ID'), '$') as survey_id
    ,get(XMLGET(q.value, 'CLIENT_ID'), '$') as client_id
    ,get(XMLGET(XMLGET(c.value, 'RESPONSE'), 'QUESTION'), '$') as question
    ,get(XMLGET(XMLGET(c.value, 'RESPONSE'), 'ANSWER'), '$' ) as answer
FROM TEST_XML,
  LATERAL FLATTEN(GET(src_xml, '$')) q,
  LATERAL FLATTEN(get(q.value, '$')) c
WHERE get(c.value, '@')='COMMENTS'
```

which gives the results:

```
SURVEY_ID   CLIENT_ID   QUESTION        ANSWER
1           "ABC"       "Do you drink?" "Yes"
1           "ABC"       "Do you Smoke?" "Yes"
2           "DEF"       "Do you drink?" "No"
```

Comment: You are the best, Simeon ! Your answers are so simple to understand. In official snowflake documentation, I see FLATTEN arguments like INPUT, PATH, RECURSIVE and MODE. Use cases like mine do not require such arguments, is it? Answers suggested by others in other snowflake XML related questions mention about ```input=>to_array```. Also I see ```:"$"``` being used in many places. Your answers look so straight forward to understand.

Comment: @vvazza true that FLATTEN normally has `input=>src` I just copied the SQL you passed and given it worked didn't think anymore of it.. also thanks for the compliment, I tend to try say how I would explain the steps to you, if I was sitting next to you, and I try avoid jumping to many steps, so that each part can be seen for how it fits together in the bigger picture.

Comment: but yes the flattens work in the above and in this form `LATERAL FLATTEN(input=>GET(src_xml, '$')) q,` and in the TABLE(FLATTEN()) form `TABLE(FLATTEN(input=>GET(src_xml, '$'))) q,`

Comment: Simeon, my sincere apologies. ```<SURVEYDATA>``` is at the same level as ```<DATAEXPORT>```. When i used the same logic that you provided, am able to get only one comment from SURVEY_ID 1

Comment: @vvazza there are two parts to a problem like this, unpacking parts of the data, and looping across the looped data. So if `SURVEYDATA` is at the same level as `DATAEXPORT` which to be honest doesn't sound likely, as something needs to be the root node in the XML, but anyways, picking your data to loop across is the first step of unpacking. Surely after three questions, you have learnt how to unpack the XML you have.

Comment: Both ```<DATA_EXPORT>``` and ```<SURVEYDATA>``` are the root level. When I loop through ```SURVEYDATA``` to get SURVEYID,  and then loop through ```COMMENTS```, I get 1 survey id and 1 comment response. ```SELECT GET(XMLGET(D.VALUE, 'SURVEY_ID'),'$') AS SURVEY_ID
, GET(XMLGET(XMLGET(Q.VALUE, 'RESPONSE'), 'QUESTION'),'$') AS QUESTION
FROM TEST_XML
, LATERAL FLATTEN (GET(SRC_XML,'$'))D
, LATERAL FLATTEN (GET(D.VALUE, '$'))Q
WHERE GET(Q.VALUE,'@')='COMMENTS';``` This query is fetching me "Do you drink?" and "Do you drink?". "Do you smoke?" is not pulling up

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231635/discussion-between-vvazza-and-simeon-pilgrim).

Comment: Simeon, In the XML that i sent you yesterday, if there are two COMMENTS in first LEVELDATA and if there is only one COMMENTS in second LEVELDATA, second entry is getting NULL value. I tried all options, but LEVELDATA with multiple COMMENTS returned value, but single COMMENTS returned only NULL. Any idea what's going wrong here?

Comment: @vvazza it seems snowflakes handling of XML is broken, and you have to hack around it. this question has the tricks, it's gross: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67283821/parsing-xml-with-unknown-structure-in-snowflake

Comment: Sure, will check that question in detail.  Would I require TO_ARRAY for my case?