# Parsing XML with unknown structure in Snowflake

Tags: sql, xml, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a bunch of XML files that define tree hierarchies (relations between ID:s) via nested tags. I want to parse it to tabular format using Snowflake's SQL syntax for semi-structured data. For XML files with known structure, I know how to do it. But for these trees, the structure is unknown at parsing time, in which case I don't know how to solve it. The generic pattern that repeats is

```
<Nodes>
    <Node>
        ...
    </Node>
</Nodes>
```

See below for example data and desired output.

Is there a way to accomplish this using Snowflake's SQL syntax?

Example data:

```
<Nodes>
    <Node Id="1">
        <Nodes>
            <Node Id="2">
            </Node>
            <Node Id="3">
                <Nodes>
                    <Node Id="4">
                    </Node>
                    <Node Id="5">
                        <Nodes>
                            <Node Id="6">
                            </Node>
                        </Nodes>
                    </Node>
                    <Node Id="7">
                    </Node>
                </Nodes>
            </Node>
            <Node Id="8">
            </Node>
        </Nodes>
    </Node>
    <Node Id="9">
        <Nodes>
            <Node Id="10">
            </Node>
        </Nodes>
    </Node>
</Nodes>
```

Desired tabular output is:

```
|-----------|---------|
| parent_id | node_id |
|-----------|---------|
|      null |       1 |
|         1 |       2 |
|         1 |       3 |
|         3 |       4 |
|         3 |       5 |
|         5 |       6 |
|         3 |       7 |
|         1 |       8 |
|      null |       9 |
|         9 |      10 |
|-----------|---------|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So RECURSIVE is the property on FLATTEN you want to use here:

```
with data as (
    select parse_xml('<Nodes>
    <Node Id="1">
        <Nodes>
            <Node Id="2">
            </Node>
            <Node Id="3">
                <Nodes>
                    <Node Id="4">
                    </Node>
                    <Node Id="5">
                        <Nodes>
                            <Node Id="6">
                            </Node>
                        </Nodes>
                    </Node>
                    <Node Id="7">
                    </Node>
                </Nodes>
            </Node>
            <Node Id="8">
            </Node>
        </Nodes>
    </Node>
    <Node Id="9">
        <Nodes>
            <Node Id="10">
            </Node>
        </Nodes>
    </Node>
</Nodes>') as xml
)
select 
    GET(f.value, '@Id') as id
    ,f.path as path
    ,len(path) as p_len
from data,
    TABLE(FLATTEN(INPUT=>get(xml,'$'), recursive=>true)) f
    where get(f.value, '@') = 'Node'
;
```

gives:

```
ID  PATH    P_LEN
1   [0] 3
2   [0]['$']['$'][0]    16
3   [0]['$']['$'][1]    16
4   [0]['$']['$'][1]['$']['$'][0]   29
5   [0]['$']['$'][1]['$']['$'][1]   29
6   [0]['$']['$'][1]['$']['$'][1]['$']['$'] 39
7   [0]['$']['$'][1]['$']['$'][2]   29
8   [0]['$']['$'][2]    16
9   [1] 3
10  [1]['$']['$']   13
```

from this you can now rebuild the hierarchy by find all the matches of path and taking the longest match.

OR

you can do a double nested loop like:

```
select 
    GET(f1.value, '@Id') as id
    ,GET(f2.value, '@Id') as id
    ,f1.value
    ,f2.*
    , get(f2.value, '@') 
from data,
    TABLE(FLATTEN(INPUT=>get(xml,'$'), recursive=>true)) f1,
    TABLE(FLATTEN(INPUT=>GET(xmlget(f1.value,'Nodes'), '$'))) f2
    where get(f1.value, '@') = 'Node'
;
```

BUT it doesn't give you the first row, and snowflake behaves differently with expanding the nodes

```
<node>
  <nodes>
    <node></node>
  </nodes>
<node>
```

and

```
<node>
  <nodes>
    <node></node>
    <node></node>
  </nodes>
<node>
```

which means you have to try handle both which is really gross.

EDIT:

So you can get closer but noting that if the second sub-case happens you can get node name `get(f2.value, '@')  = 'Node'` thus we have something we can stuff into `IFF` and in the first case, the `value` of the flatten is `'Node'` thus we can hard code fetch the parents -> nodes -> node, thus:

```
select 
    GET(f1.value, '@Id') as parent_id
    ,iff(get(f2.value, '@')  = 'Node', GET(f2.value, '@Id'), GET(xmlget(xmlget(f1.value,'Nodes'),'Node'), '@Id')) as child_id
from data,
    TABLE(FLATTEN(INPUT=>get(xml,'$'), recursive=>true)) f1,
    TABLE(FLATTEN(INPUT=>GET(xmlget(f1.value,'Nodes'), '$'))) f2
    where get(f1.value, '@') = 'Node'
    and (get(f2.value, '@')  = 'Node' OR f2.value = 'Node')
;
```

gives you:

```
PARENT_ID   CHILD_ID
1   2
1   3
1   8
3   4
3   5
3   7
5   6
9   10
```

which is only missing the `NULL, 1` and `NULL, 9` rows that you wanted.

EDIT 2

So going back to my original suggestion, pulling the node id's and the paths out and then doing a LEFT JOIN on the nodes with a QUALIFY to keep the longest match can be done like so, and gives the desired output:

```
with data as (
    select parse_xml('<Nodes>
    <Node Id="1">
        <Nodes>
            <Node Id="2">
            </Node>
            <Node Id="3">
                <Nodes>
                    <Node Id="4">
                    </Node>
                    <Node Id="5">
                        <Nodes>
                            <Node Id="6">
                            </Node>
                        </Nodes>
                    </Node>
                    <Node Id="7">
                    </Node>
                </Nodes>
            </Node>
            <Node Id="8">
            </Node>
        </Nodes>
    </Node>
    <Node Id="9">
        <Nodes>
            <Node Id="10">
                     </Node>
        </Nodes>
    </Node>
</Nodes>') as xml
), nodes AS (
select 
    GET(f1.value, '@Id') as id
    ,f1.path as path
    ,len(path) as l_path
from data,
    TABLE(FLATTEN(INPUT=>get(xml,'$'), recursive=>true)) f1
    where get(f1.value, '@') = 'Node'
)
SELECT p.id as parent_id
    ,c.id as child_id
FROM nodes c
LEFT JOIN nodes p
    ON LEFT(c.path,p.l_path) = p.path AND c.id <> p.id
QUALIFY row_number() over (partition by c.id order by p.l_path desc ) = 1
;
```

gives:

```
PARENT_ID   CHILD_ID
null    1
1       2
1       3
3       4
3       5
5       6
3       7
1       8
null    9
9       10
```

Comment: Wow, amazing answer, thanks! I will need some time to digest and play around with it before accepting though.